# Coefficients of a Quartic Polynomial Function

Tags: number-theory

In the quartic polynomial function: $$f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
Given that this function has only real zeroes and real coefficients, and that $|f(\sqrt{-1})|=1$, how can I find what the coefficients are. We know that the coefficient for $x^4$ is 1, but how can we find out what the other coefficients are?

Answer (score 8):

Let the $4$ real zeroes of $f(x)$ be $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. Also recall that $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

$$f(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$$
$$\therefore f(i)=(i-x_1)(i-x_2)(i-x_3)(i-x_4)$$

$$\therefore \left|f(i)\right|=\sqrt{1+{x_1}^2}\sqrt{1+{x_2}^2}\sqrt{1+{x_3}^2}\sqrt{1+{x_4}^2}=1\implies x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4= 0$$

$$\therefore f(x)=x^4\implies a=b=c=d=0$$